# Complicated function definite integration problem

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I have a function with two variables (s,t):

```
 AT = 0.0000792456 E^((0.08636 - 0.141381 t + 
 0.0169775 (-0.282843 + Sqrt[0.08 + t])) (73.3877 + 
 Log[s])) s (-0.212432 + 0.990813 (73.3877 + Log[s])) + 
 4.2148 E^(-2.13198 t) s^(0.875076 - 1.06027 t + 
 1.07567 (-0.282843 + Sqrt[0.08 + t])) Sin[
 1/2 \[Pi] (0.875076 - 1.06027 t + 
 1.07567 (-0.282843 + Sqrt[0.08 + t]))]
```

and I have to obtain the next definite integral:

```
Integrate[AT, {t, 0, 1}]
```

which will be a function of s, but Mathematica does not calculate this integral, and I obtain the input expression after evaluation:

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I suspect that a numerical integral is the best that you can do, but applying assumptions about the value of `s` (e.g. `s>0` might help)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are satisfied with a [`ParametricFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricFunction.html) object, you could use:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{f'[t] == AT, f[0] == 0}, f[1], {t,0,1}, s];
```

The output is a [`ParametricFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricFunction.html) that gives you the value of the integral for a given value of `s`. For example, you can plot it:

```
Plot[sol[s],{s,0,1}]
```

> [image]

Compare to evaluating the definite integral numerically:

```
Block[{s = .3}, NIntegrate[AT, {t, 0, 1}]]
sol[.3]
```

> 0.692984
>
> 0.692984

Answer (score 2):

You could do this numerically:

```
f[ss_] := NIntegrate[AT /. s -> ss, {t, 0, 1}]
```